# Angular module config not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get my head around AngularJS and ran into a problem.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    console.log('Configuring module "myApp"');

    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {templateUrl: 'partial/dashboard', controller: DashboardController});
    $routeProvider.when('/menu', {templateUrl: 'partial/other', controller: OtherController});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 }]);
```

To my understanding the configuration function should be called when the module gets loaded. **But it does not!**

I have the `ng-app="myApp"` directive on the `<body>` tag. And scripts loaded just before the body closing tag in the correct order (as far as that matters).

```
    <script src="angular.js"></script>      
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="services.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm pretty sure I must be overlooking something trivial here. There should be a message printed to the console. But it remains empty with no errors or warnings whatsoever.

**The parts of the app not depending on the routes runs just fine.**

#### Update: simplified version of my service.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', function ($provide) {
    $provide.factory('myService', function ($http) {
        var service = function () {
            ...
            service implementation
            ...
        };

        return new service();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah... it should. Are you sure all scripts are getting loaded? Are there any errors in console? I just posted your code to a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fciVIcCWGtV4HG8rM4fh?p=preview) to check for any typo, and it works as expected. I can only suspect on your `myApp.services`, would you post it?

Comment: @CaioToOn - It was indeed a coding error in my services. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I see you posted the correct answer below; one tiny correction to above however is *when* the `config` runs. Unlike services, which run the first time they are injected, `config` blocks are run at a specified point in the AngularJS bootstrap. In other words, the `config` will *always* run and will always run *prior* to your app executing.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller - Does that count for all modules or only the modules instantiated by the injector?

Comment: Modules don't get instantiated by the injector; services do. The `config`, though will execute for your app module and any modules it declares as dependencies, plus all of their dependencies, etc.

Comment: got the same problem and got scratching my head for hours. But after reading your question, I realized that my problem is just the missing ng-app directive ahahha. thanks for this question.

Comment: I got the same problem. My code is not working because method `.run` is not being called. When I open chrome's debugger, `.run` are called correctly (i'm running Ionic app by `ionic serve` command)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems that the method I used for defining the service was overriding my `myApp` module.

**This is the overriding line**

```
angular.module('myApp', function ($provide) ...
```

This code simply redefines the `myApp` module and adds a function to configure that one.

---

I refactored service.js to this simplified version and it started to work.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.factory('securityService', function () {
    return SomeFancyServiceObject();
});
```

Comment: Ran into this today. I'm usually pretty careful, but I'm dealing with multiple modules and I couldn't figure it out until I came here....and then it was so obvious. Good catch!

Comment: Thank you.. In my case, I was using the same module name for app.js and MyControllers.js. I added an empty [] to my MyControllers.js and realized it was overriding the main module.. Trick is to use distinct names for your modules.

Comment: Same thing. I was too nervous during the hackathon trying to understand why my almost hello world app doesn't work.

Comment: 5 years later and your question and answer just saved my ***. I've been hitting my head against a wall for like 4+ hours over this and never would've figured that out on my own. I had some empty brackets sitting on a controller's .module() declaration that I must've added absent mindedly and completely forgot had existed. I never would've noticed without this answer. THANK YOU

Answer (score 11):

I was missing ng-app="myApp" inside my html tag - and I realized this while reading your question :-)

Comment: sigh. what a small mistake made that cost me an hour of debugging

Comment: Wasted a while - zero error messages..  and realizing that app.config is not even getting called on created a new app....   all because i fat fingered `np-app=`  instead of `ng-app`   I was about to rip out ngroute and pull in ui-router !   Geez.   I must need an angular code spellchecker..     thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I usually see routing applied by chaining them together:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/dashboard', {templateUrl: 'partial/dashboard', controller: DashboardController})
    .when('/menu', {templateUrl: 'partial/other', controller: OtherController})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});
```

Can't see why yours would not work, but might be worth a go.

Comment: The problem is that the config(fn) never gets called. So the code in the function is never executed.