# Angular module config does not executed

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am implementing a sample from the instruction of [Dan Wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs).
I encountered same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877925/angular-module-config-not-called), I have tried his solution and investigated through my source code but there is not any redefinition of the module.

Here is my code

// main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/app/',
    urlArgs: 'v=1.0'
});

require(
    [
        'config/myapp',
        ..... [dependencies]
    ],
    function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
```

// myapp.js

```
'use strict';

define(['services/routeResolver'], function () {

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'routeResolverServices', 'ui.bootstrap', 'breeze.angular']);

console.log('A'); //working
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    console.log('C'); // this line does not work
}]);
console.log('B'); //working
app.run(['$rootScope',
    function ($rootScope) {

    }]);

return app;

});
```

I can do `console.log` to print 'A', 'B'; but 'C' is not printed out, it is indicating that the function inside `.config` does not work.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any console errors ?

Comment: @JayanthaLalSirisena I don't get the error for now, but this is the cause that make my app works incorrectly. Inside the .config, I have to initialize a variable such as app.register = {...} but it never be set because of the mentioned problem, it would throw error about undefined value after then. The console.log('C') should have to run while it didn't

Comment: Did you check your code calls to `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);` line ?

Comment: There are 4 months passed. I quit from RequireJs and moved to https://oclazyload.readme.io/ instead. It is more stable and flexible. I have used it on my project with multiple different configuration and it works pretty well.

I do not have the answer for this question as well. But if someone else want to find another way not RequireJs, could refer to the mentioned option.